# Передача параметров в функции

Tags: c++

Сам код:

```
// #include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

double MyF2(double &x)
{
    cout << "Размер x: " << sizeof(x) << " Значение x=" << x << " Значение *x="<< x << endl;
    x += 10;
    return x;
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int a = 2;
    double b = 7;
    cout << "  a = " << a << "  Размер a: " << sizeof(a);
    cout << "  b = " << b << "  Размер b: " << sizeof(b) << endl;

    cout << "(17) Результат MyF2 : " << MyF2(a) << endl;

    cout << "(23) Результат MyF2 : " << MyF2(++b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

При компилировании вылетает ошибка. В чем ошибка ?

Comment: Как "в чем"? Вы что, сами не можете прочитать сообщение об ошибке? `double` и `int` - это два разных, никак не связанных друг с другом типа. Вы пытаетесь передать `int` там, где требуется ссылка на `double`.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь: [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Вы передаете в функцию, принимающую *ссылку* на `double`, переменную типа `int`. Подчеркиваю - не значение, а ссылку!

И что будет, если в функции будет присвоено значение по этой ссылке - скажем, 8 байт `double` туда, где реально хранятся 4 байта `int`? уж точно ничего хорошего.

Потому такие несоответствия запрещены.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключается в том, что вы передаётся переменную другого типа. Изменил код, теперь должен работать. У вас был `int a`, я изменил на `double a;`

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

double MyF2(double &x)
{
    cout << "Размер x: " << sizeof(x) << " Значение x=" << x << " Значение *x="<< x << endl;
    x += 10;
    return x;
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    double a = 2;
    double b = 7;
    cout << "  a = " << a << "  Размер a: " << sizeof(a);
    cout << "  b = " << b << "  Размер b: " << sizeof(b) << endl;

    cout << "(17) Результат MyF2 : " << MyF2(a) << endl;

    cout << "(23) Результат MyF2 : " << MyF2(++b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

`#include <iostream>` вместо include `"iostream"`

Comment: Из-за этого не будет ошибки. При кавычках файл будет искаться сначала в текущем каталоге, а если не найден, то поведение такое же, как и при угловых скобках.